# How to create threads only on performance cores in MAC OSX on Apple silicon?

Tags: multithreading, macos, performance, apple-silicon, affinity

does anyone of you know, how to create threads only on performance cores under Apple OSX with new asymmetric core Apple chips (M1, M1 Pro...)?

I am referencing these two guides from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/tuning-your-code-s-performance-for-apple-silicon

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheTaskLevel.html

I know you can create threads with assigned Quality of Service (QoS) classes and this can help to place thread on performance cores according to Apple guides.

```
pthread_attr_t qosAttribute;
pthread_attr_init(&qosAttribute);
pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np(&qosAttribute, QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0);
pthread_create(&thread, &qosAttribute, f, NULL);
```

But I need to be sure, that thread is placed only on performance core and not to the efficiency one for my audio application. Is there any solution for this??

For instance under Linux there is a function for setting affinity pthread_setaffinity_np,

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html

where you can run thread on specific core if you set correct mask. But this function is 1. not available under OSX and 2. I cannot find any information how to get mask of performance and efficiency cores.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks Martin

I have tried set QoS class to highest level QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE which somehow works, but I need to be sure, no efficiency core will be used for my threads.

Comment: https://eclecticlight.co/2022/11/28/can-you-game-core-allocation-on-apple-silicon/

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. Threads can be confined to E cores; but high QoS still allows the possibility of a thread to run on an E core (even though it should normally be a P core). There doesn't seem a way to restrict to P cores.